# Move dock between displays keyboard shortcut (or keep on both displays)

Tags: keyboard, display, dock

I would like to move my dock via keyboard shortcut between displays.  When I connect my second display (which I use as my active display) and try to use the pad to 'learn' this new display is the main one it takes probably 20-30 seconds of moving my mouse up and down before the display finally jumps.

I was wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut that exists or I could create that could handle this action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought perhaps the default <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to toggle **Turn Dock Hiding On/Off** would work. I considered that, depending on which display was active, toggling the Dock would cause it to appear on whichever display was active at the time. However, I find that the Dock remains on the given display.

However, I believe the solution is simply to explain how the mouse or trackpad is used to move the Dock.

The rule is that by moving the cursor 1" below the bottom of the given display, the Dock will then move.

Comment: Moving the cursor below the display?  Not sure that makes complete sense to me...

Comment: When you move the cursor to bottom of the display, it doesn't actually "move" below the bottom of the display. However, Mac OSX continues tracking the cursor movement, and if that movement goes 1" below the bottom of the screen, then the Dock will switch to that display. In your original description, you stated you were "...[spending] 20-30 seconds of moving my mouse up and down before the display finally jumps." What you didn't realize is that, sometime in there, you'd moved the cursor 1" below the bottom of the display, in effect causing the Dock to shift.

Comment: A corollary of the [1" below display] feature is that users can seemingly move the Dock between displays seemingly randomly, causing them to wonder how to get the Dock to move back to their main display.

Comment: I see now, move it as though there is space below the display but obviously the mouse is hitting the lower container.  It works now that I understand.  Would be helpful if there was a keyboard shortcut to automate this instead of having to use the mouse but at least now I know how to control better.

Comment: Create a feature request, perhaps something along the lines of, "Create a shortcut that causes Dock to move to whichever screen the cursor is currently on." ( http://www.apple.com/feedback/ )

Comment: I'm going to have to do that.  The moving the cursor below the display is far from 100% correct result.  I've found myself moving cursor down for 5-10 seconds before I finally move around the display, click a few things, then try again and hope it works this time.  Basically back where I started.

Comment: FINALLY an answer that makes sense! This has been bugging me for years. You can always get the dock to appear on any given monitor by first getting the cursor all the way to the edge, THEN with a second gesture flicking down with gusto, in a way that would normally move your cursor at least one inch. The cursor won't move (since you're already at the edge), but the *intent* to go down an inch is recorded, and this will reliably get the dock to move where your cursor is!

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does *not* work for me.   The dock remains for the most part anchored to my MacBook Pro and does not shift to my external display when it's active and I move the mouse to its bottom.

Comment: nfortunately, one of my displays is arranged above my main display. I can't ever get the menu dock to that that screen. If I move my cursor down past the bottom of the display, cursor then appears on the display below.

Would be nice to have a keyboard shortcut, but apparently this arrangement is a no-go unless I am ok with opening apps on another display and then moving them to that display.